# Can we find unions of the sets which solve multivariate polynomial equation systems and what are they called?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry we have a concept called **algebraic variety** which is a multivariate polynomial equation system

$$\cases{p_1(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)=0\\p_2(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)=0\\\vdots\\p_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)=0}$$

or more specifically the solution set to such an equation system.

From a geometry perspective this is rather powerful and expressive.

Already with one equation we can express many shapes, with varieties we can select **cups** of these sets.

But even more powerful would be if we could also express unions. does there exist any arithmetic or algebraic operation which allows us to take the **union** of a number of solution sets to multivariate polynomial equation systems?

Answer (score 2):

To each variety $X \subseteq k^n$ (where $k$ is an algebraically closed field) we can attach a radical ideal $I(X)$ defined by

$$ I(X) =  \{f \in k[x_1,...,x_n] | \forall x \in X, f(x) = 0\}$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties,

$$ I(X \cup Y) = I(X) \cap I(Y)$$ since it must be functions that vanish on both sets.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I read more about such ideals?